# Python module import fails when in file but from interpreter works

Tags: python

I have a module that I am unable to import from the import statement in the top of a file, but the same import works fine in the same interpreter.

Any thoughts on this?

```
➜  ~ python /home/barrett/Git/bnr_robot_software/src/bnr_robot_cloud /bnr_robot_cloud_common/src/bnr_robot_cloud_common/my_unique_script_name.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/barrett/Git/bnr_robot_software/src/bnr_robot_cloud/bnr_robot_cloud_common/src/bnr_robot_cloud_common/my_unique_script_name.py", line 1, in <module>
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService
ImportError: No module named servicebus


➜  ~ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService
>>>
```

Comment: `import azure` from your script and print `azure.__file__` just for a quick check

Comment: Yup. I see what you are getting at. I'm not sure why this is raising it's head now. Let me refactor my module names and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Do you have python 2.7 and 3 installed if so you might be opening it with python 3

Comment: not possible since in both cases OP prefixes command by `python`

Comment: Fabre your hint lead me to the fix. I had a custom module on my path named azure. I renamed it to something distinct and it resolved the module fine. Please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept.